# adding shadow on the bottom of List item of Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, shadow

I want to add shadow to bottom of my ListView item !!
I tried paddingEdageLenght but no change happened ! 
I added circular edges but i can't add the shadow below the item

this is my list item xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="5sp" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/site_image"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/site_name"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/site_image"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/site_description"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/site_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/site_image"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my ListView xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/near_sites"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="5sp"
        android:dividerHeight="10sp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

any help ?

Comment: Go to this [http://www.anotherandroidblog.com/2011/06/29/drop-shadow-linearlayout/](http://www.anotherandroidblog.com/2011/06/29/drop-shadow-linearlayout/)

Comment: now, we can use cardview with cardElevation and cardRaduis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `list_view_item`, add a *dummy* View after your `RelativeLayout` and wrap them all at vertical `LinearLayout` like this:

```
<LinearLayout
         android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout>
        ...
        ...
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/shadow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp" <!--or your needed height value-->
        android:background="@drawable/shadow_drawable">     
    </View>

</LinearLayout>
```

and at drawable folder add the new shadow_drawable.xml and put this at it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android=”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android”>    
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@color/#000000" <!--black-->
        android:endColor="@color/#FFFFFF" <!--white-->
        android:angle="90" <!-- angle of the gradient-->
        >
    </gradient>
</shape>
```

Comment: In Material Design the divider is less dark than your proposed solution. So, it's better is you use dark grey as your start color in the shape. Like that: android:startColor="@android:color/darker_gray"

Answer (score 1):

you have to add footerview in listview,

how to add footerview check bellow code,

```
private View footerView;
footerView = ((LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.listview_footer, null, false);
ListView.addFooterView(footerView);
```

so, what ever you can do, in footer view.

Comment: what does (R.layout.listview_footer) contain ?

Comment: hi, this is xml layout.

Answer (score 1):

You can make 9-patch image for border with shadow effect.

Create a new drawable resource file named "border.xml" in "res/drawable" and write the following code-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient android:startColor="#ddd" android:endColor="#555" android:type="linear" />
            <corners android:radius="0dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:right=".5dp" android:left=".5dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:top=".5dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="0dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Just put `android:background="@drawable/border"` where you want to apply border.

You can change in `android:right`,`android:left`,`android:top` and `android:bottom` to give size to border. you can also make change in `android:shape` for more effect.

Hope its help for you !

Comment: Hello, did you try this?