# Android shadow color for layout

Tags: android, android-layout, background-color, shadow

I have developed a `listView` for my app. My UI is simple `flat UI`, here is a snapshot:

[image]

when I searched internet for better interfaces I found this for example:
[image]

As you see in this sample, background colors have shadows at the bottom. Is there a way that I can color my Layout background like this? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22936520/adding-shadow-on-the-bottom-of-list-item-of-listview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve a shadow effect I'd guess that it's better to use a `layer-list` with two items, one with the solid color and the second item would be a gradient coming from transparent to a black color with an alpha value.

Here's how this would look like (needs to be placed in `res/drawable/`):

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ff33b5e5" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:angle="-90"
                android:endColor="#90000000"
                android:startColor="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Doing it this way, you won't need to "search" for a darker color of your solid color all the time.

Output would look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Create an XML file and named it as "gradient_effect" in Res -> Drawable folder and put below code in it

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
      android:startColor="#a0a0a0"
      android:endColor="#f5f5f5"
      android:angle="0"

      />
```

Now use this file as a background in any of your layout as you can get is like

```
android:Background= "@Drawable/gradient_effect"
```

Set above line as an attribute for any of you view or layout in xml file

Answer (score 0):

**This can help too!**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:angle="90"
            android:endColor="#A2000000"
            android:startColor="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>
```